# AND Gate with 2 NPN Transistors

Tags: transistors, switches, bjt, npn

How can I stop the current flowing through the LED when the second switch is open (as it is on this circuit)? A lot of people suggests that just by using MOSFETs the problem will be solved because in steady state the current is not allowed through gate (base), but instead, if I stick with BJTs there is nothing that I can do about it? Maybe placing a buffer somewhere in this circuit that tells me when it's fully on or off?

[image]

What I really want to obtain from this circuit is to light a single LED or to power some load resistance only if both switches are closed (or the batteries are plugged in for example) from the parallel batteries.

Comment: Your schematic is very unreadable because it does not follow common practice which is to have GND at the bottom and supply at the top.

Comment: I'm sorry for this, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to do from explanations.

Comment: If you redraw your schematic using this site's built-in schematic editor and adhere to common schematic conventions, I suspect it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: You could achieve what you want by binning both transistors and connecting the two switches in series with the LED and the 100Ohm resistor. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Finbarr, I'm trying to make a parallel battery supply which will power something only when both batteries are plugged in (2 switches can simulate this behaviour). How can I achieve this?

Comment: On/Off switch that you only turn on when you plug in both batteries?

Comment: The challenge you have is that with the batteries connected in parallel you lose any ability to tell if one is one is fitted but the other isn't, so you would need to use a couple of diodes to isolate them. Then I would suggest putting the transistors between your load and ground so the base current doesn't go through your load.

Comment: Interesting request, if I understand you. But you haven't provided any specifications so far as I can tell. Just a question which really isn't well-stated, let alone well specified. No idea about the battery technology (and it matters) or about the range of voltages the two batteries might have and still be validly connected to a load or info about the load itself. Conceptual schematics can be suggested, I suppose. But not correct ones for your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, where the signal generators are your batteries.

However, that's a lot of components to test for both batteries present, and you loose voltage off the top through those diodes and mosfets.

You need to consider the rationality of what you are really trying to do here. Does it really matter if only one battery is installed? Will it just mean whatever you are powering will only run for half the time?

If it is critical that both batteries be installed, you may also want to consider a more mechanical solution that puts micro-switches under the batteries.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMsoyw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>